# Positioning Element vertically responsive over image

Tags: css, responsive-design, positioning, rotatetransform

How to make this green text ribbon stick to the left side of the image, so it will be there even if image size is shrinking responsively?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background-color: #00ff00;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/sports/" alt="" />
        <span class="img-label">Some Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `transform-origin:0% 0%` and remove the `top` property from span. also change `top:0` to `bottom:0` in img

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background-color: #00ff00;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/sports/" alt="" />
        <span class="img-label">Some Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: but how to make this ribbon stick to the bottom of the image and to make the ribbon not to get out of image scope

Comment: that's cool, but the ribbon gets out of the upper image border

Comment: thanks for helping! transform-origin: 0% 0%; helps me